CSS Non-standard responsive image frame
I'm trying to implement a non-standard frame for a picture of a news section. My idea is to have the picture as a lower z-index than the frame and have the frame on top of it and make them responsive. So far I had no luck.


.news-gallery-image {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

.news-gallery-image img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.news-gallery-image .news-border {
    content: url("/resources/images/gallery-image-background-holder.png");
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
<div class="mt-5 m-auto w-full">
    <!-- Swiper -->
    <div class="swiper news-swiper">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide flex-col">
                <div class="news-gallery-image">
                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bRqr97Q.png" class="image" alt="forge your deck">
                    <img class="news-border" alt="borders"/>
                </div>
                <div class="w-auto mt-2">
                    <h1 class="text-1xl text-center">
                        HOTFIX #1.23 NOW LIVE!
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide flex-col">
                <div class="news-gallery-image">
                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bRqr97Q.png" class="image" alt="forge your deck">
                    <img class="news-border" alt="borders"/>
                </div>

                <div class="w-auto mt-2">
                    <h1 class="text-1xl text-center">
                        HOTFIX #1.23 NOW LIVE!
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide flex flex-col">
                <div class="news-gallery-image">
                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bRqr97Q.png" class="image" alt="forge your deck">
                    <img class="news-border" alt="borders"/>
                </div>
                <div class="w-auto mt-2">
                    <h1 class="text-1xl text-center">
                        HOTFIX #1.23 NOW LIVE!
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




Example
Could you please give a hand with this?

looks like you have whitespace in the frame image. You will need to set the size of the inset image to be smaller than the frame, and probably trim the excess white space from the frame image

Yep, my bad there. I've used the image that Akshat provided, but didn't do the job :(

So the answer that I came up is to make the image the same size as the border view field and leaving transparent space on each side. This way the image was contained in the middle of the border where the viewport is.

It looks like to code is correct but the image is causing the issue. Try using this image
You need to set the width of the border such that it covers the image that is inside(main image to be displayed) and try to keep the aspect ratio of the border image and the back image same.


   .news-gallery-image{
        position: relative;
        width:100%;
        height:auto;
        display: flex;
        align-items:center;
        justify-content:center;
        margin-bottom:5%;
    }
        
    .news-gallery-image .backimg {
        position: relative;
        width:90%;
        margin-top:5%;
    }
        
    .news-gallery-image .news-border {
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        height:107%;
    }
    <div class="mt-5 m-auto w-full">
        <!-- Swiper -->
        <div class="swiper news-swiper">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide flex-col">
                    <div class="news-gallery-image">
                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bRqr97Q.png" class="image backimg" alt="forge your deck">
                        <img src="images/eAgUyVIv.png" class="news-border" alt="borders"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w-auto mt-2">
                        <h1 class="text-1xl text-center">
                            HOTFIX #1.23 NOW LIVE!
                        </h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide flex-col">
                    <div class="news-gallery-image">
                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bRqr97Q.png" class="image backimg" alt="forge your deck">
                        <img src="images/eAgUyVIv.png" class="news-border" alt="borders"/>
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="w-auto mt-2">
                        <h1 class="text-1xl text-center">
                            HOTFIX #1.23 NOW LIVE!
                        </h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide flex flex-col">
                    <div class="news-gallery-image">
                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bRqr97Q.png" class="image backimg" alt="forge your deck">
                        <img src="images/eAgUyVIv.png" class="news-border" alt="borders"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w-auto mt-2">
                        <h1 class="text-1xl text-center">
                            HOTFIX #1.23 NOW LIVE!
                        </h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>




Nothing change. I don't think there is a way to fit the image in the container when it's absolutely positioned. I think I need to create images as the same size as the border, so they can fit in it. I basically need a template for this specific section of the images that I make. If I understand correct. I'm kinda new to CSS
